Why am I getting preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request?
Successfully hosted my node project on Vercel but I am receiving this error, whenever I try to use the server or access the link in my client

Access to XMLHttpRequest at
'http://damian-backend.vercel.app/getMessages' from origin
'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not
allowed for a preflight request.
message.js:8

here is my index code in node
require("dotenv").config({ path: `${__dirname}/../.env` });
const express = require("express");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const cors = require("cors");
const User = require("./models/user");
const login = require("./routes/login");
const signup = require("./routes/signup");
const addPhoto = require("./routes/addGallery");
const getImages = require("./routes/getGallery");
const createMessages = require("./routes/createMessage");
const getMsg = require("./routes/getMessages");
const delImage = require("./routes/delGallery");
const connection = require("./config/connection");
const authToken = require("./middleware/authToken");
const getImage = require("./routes/getImage");
const multer = require("multer");

const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({ stora``ge });

//Getting our app
const app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.use(express.json());
app.use(morgan("dev"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.redirect("https://www.damianglory.ca/");
});

// Getting users info
app.get("/user", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const users = await User.find();
    res.status(200).json(users);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ error: error.message });
  }
});

app.post("/signup", signup);
app.post("/login", login);
app.delete("/logout");

app.post("/messages", createMessages);
app.get("/getMessages", authToken, getMsg);
app.get("/images/:id", getImage);

app.post("/addPhoto", authToken, upload.single("imgUrl"), addPhoto);
app.get("/viewImages", getImages);
app.delete("/deleteImages/:id", authToken, delImage);

connection({ app, port: process.env.PORT || 5000 });

Here is my Redux code, handling my request
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import axios from 'axios';

// Define a thunk action to fetch messages
export const fetchMessages = createAsyncThunk('message/fetchMessage', async (_, { getState }) => {
    try {
        const { token } = getState().user.logged;
        const response = await axios.get('http://damian-backend.vercel.app/getMessages', {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
            }
        });
        return response.data;
    } 
    catch (error) {
        throw error.response?.data?.error || 'An error occurred while trying to fetch message';
    }
});

export const postMessage = createAsyncThunk('messages/postMessage', async (messageData) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.post('http://damian-backend.vercel.app/messages', messageData);
        return response.data;
    }
    catch (error) {
        throw error.response?.data?.error || 'An error occurred while trying to post message';
    }
});

const initialState = {
    messages: [],
    error: null,
    status: 'Idle'
}

const messageSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'message',
    initialState: initialState,
    reducers: {},
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder
        .addCase(fetchMessages.pending, (state) => {
            state.status = 'Loading...'
        })
        .addCase(fetchMessages.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.status = 'Succeeded';
            state.messages = action.payload;
            state.error = null;
        })
        .addCase(fetchMessages.rejected, (state, action) => {
            state.status = 'Failed';
            state.messages = [];
            state.error = action.error.message;
        })
        .addCase(postMessage.pending, (state) => {
            state.status = 'Loading...'
        })
        .addCase(postMessage.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.status = 'Succeeded';
            state.messages.push(action.payload);
            state.error = null;
        })
        .addCase(postMessage.rejected, (state, action) => {
            state.status = 'Failed';
            state.messages = [];
            state.error = action.error.message;
        })
    }
});

export default messageSlice.reducer;

